# Connecting to multiple social logins within HWIOauthBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, hwioauthbundle

I'm trying to arrange being able to login with a social network (initially LinkedIn, but it could be any other, or self-generated from FosUserBundle), and then adding new connections to the same user, via Twitter, FB, Github, etc.

The difficulty is connecting the multiple account connections within FosUser and the HWIOauthBundles. In order to collect as much data as I can, and be able to easily add additional connections to services, I'd really like to have each new connection as a one-to-many record. IE: The initial login with LinkedIn creates a FosUser record, and a new row in a 'socialLogin' table, the next (say login with Twitter) adds a new row to the 'socialLogin' table, that refers back to the fosUser.id.

How can I use the currently logged in (Fos)user as part of the new record that HWIOauth would generate? The end result would be, being able to login with any known user to get into the same account.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is actually easy. First check out [Symfony2: How to login using OAuth (HWIOAuthBundle) + custom roles (by default and loaded from DB)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18264800/symfony2-how-to-login-using-oauth-hwioauthbundle-custom-roles-by-default-a) which is a great how-to for HwiOAuthBundle, and then scroll down and carefully look at  public function loadUserByOAuthUserResponse(){ ... } section.

From there, your workflow will be checking the provider name from the response object. And then based on the provider name, you can update your user (use email for searching). However, with twitter you may have problem because twitter doesn't supply user email. So you need to ask your user for that email address and after you get that, you may need to merge current user account (for twitter based reg, consider it as a temporary a/c) with previous user account with this email.

Otherwise, if your user is already logged in using form/other-social-login (before connecting with twitter) you can add his twitter details once he connects with it. But you need to store user's currently logged in details in session (so that you can fetch it after user comes back with twitter token)

Hope it helps

Comment: This still appears to be using data retrieved from the various accounts to connect them. I have different email addresses on FB & Linkedin, and other sites. I'm trying to create an initial FosUser-based account, and keep adding new social accounts to that, avoiding any need to search for any information, which might not even be there.

Answer (score 0):

First step would be to create the relation between the user entity and the social_data table and the rest is all about overriding the custom user provider FOSUBUserProvider.php, which I believe you already have started doing as you have FOSUserBundle and HWIOAuthBundle working together.

I will make some edits with actual code later, but I had to answer this to get you on the track until then.